# solana web3.js sendTransaction Program failed: invalid program argument

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I built a demo project using solang solidity, and successfully deployed the contract to solana devnet
This is Program ID: 6qv4P3v732FZen4Yq6tAgnpTraV12jkc5sAHpXoL7DtX

When I use @solana/web3.js to call the contract view function, the operation fails and an error occurs:

**Program 6qv4P3v732FZen4Yq6tAgnpTraV12jkc5sAHpXoL7DtX failed: invalid program argument**

solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

contract Test {
    
    uint private value = 666;

    function getValue() external view returns(uint) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

javascript

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js")
const bufferLayout = require("@solana/buffer-layout")
const fs = require('fs')
const bs58 = require('bs58')

async function main() {
    
    const privateKey = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile("./private.key", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve(data)
        })
    })
    
    const secretKey = Buffer.from(bs58.decode(privateKey), "utf-8")
    const fromWallet = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey)

    console.log( "wallet.address=" , fromWallet.publicKey.toBase58() )

    const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'))

    const { value: { blockhash } } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext()
    console.log( "blockhash=", blockhash )

    const transaction = new web3.Transaction()

    let methodStruct = {
        index: 1,
        layout: bufferLayout.struct([
            bufferLayout.u8('instruction')
        ])
    }

    let data = Buffer.alloc(methodStruct.layout.span);
    methodStruct.layout.encode({instruction: methodStruct.index}, data)
    console.log( data  )

    const programId = new web3.PublicKey('6qv4P3v732FZen4Yq6tAgnpTraV12jkc5sAHpXoL7DtX');

    transaction.add(
        new web3.TransactionInstruction({
            keys: [],
            programId: programId,
            data,
        })
    )

    console.log( await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [fromWallet]) )
}

main()
```

Test.json

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "Test",
  "instructions": [
    {
      "name": "new",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": true,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "name": "getValue",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "name": "dataAccount",
          "isMut": false,
          "isSigner": false,
          "isOptional": false
        }
      ],
      "args": [],
      "returns": "u256"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's so weird! I tried changing the index, but the call still failed.

Comment: Thank you all for your attention